# How to wrap a TCanvas around existing pixel data?

Tags: delphi, graphics, delphi-xe2

**Question**

I have an array of 32 bit pixel data that holds a bitmap image.

```
TPixel = packed record
  B: Byte;
  G: Byte;
  R: Byte;
  A: Byte;
end;

Size = MyBitmapWidth * MyBitmapHeight;

MyBitmapData : array[0..Size-1] of TPixel;
```

Is it possible to create a new TCanvas object and attach it to my existing pixel data? The canvas object will also need to have a handle assigned to it.

**Background**

I'm using a thirdparty library that creates the bitmap data (as an array of 32 bit pixels). I would like to use the same pixel data in another function that takes TCanvas.Handle as a parameter.

Comment: If the function takes `TCanvas.Handle` as its argument, then you don't *really* need a `TCanvas`. What you need is an `HDC` — a handle to a Windows device context.

Comment: I've been writing an answer explaining why it isn't possible, but now I think it might be. It would require being able to create an `HBitmap` that holds a reference to the pixel buffer, then creating a DC (with `CreateCompatibleDC`), and finally selecting the bitmap into the DC (with `SelectObject`). The only part I'm not sure about is the first; I can't tell from the documentation whether `CreateDIBitmap` or `CreateDIBSection` retain references to the original data. (`TCanvas` is irrelevant to the process, but if you really need one, just assign `Handle := hDC` when you're ready.)

Answer (score 1):

Depending of the orientation of the Data in your Array you might have a need to change the direction by something like:
pscanLine32[j].rgbReserved := Arr[i * Width + Height - j].A;

```
type
  TPixel = packed record
    B: Byte;
    G: Byte;
    R: Byte;
    A: Byte;
  end;

  TMyBitmapData = array of TPixel;

type
  pRGBQuadArray = ^TRGBQuadArray;
  TRGBQuadArray = ARRAY [0 .. $EFFFFFF] OF TRGBQuad;

Procedure FillBitMap(var bmp: TBitMap; Arr: TMyBitmapData; Width, Height: Integer);
var
  pscanLine32: pRGBQuadArray;
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  if not Assigned(bmp) then
    bmp := TBitMap.Create;
  bmp.PixelFormat := pf32Bit;
  bmp.ignorepalette := true;
  bmp.Width := Width;
  bmp.Height := Height;
  for i := 0 to bmp.Height - 1 do
  begin
    pscanLine32 := bmp.Scanline[i];
    for j := 0 to bmp.Width - 1 do
    begin
      pscanLine32[j].rgbReserved := Arr[i * Width + j].A;
      pscanLine32[j].rgbBlue := Arr[i * Width + j].B;
      pscanLine32[j].rgbRed := Arr[i * Width + j].R;
      pscanLine32[j].rgbGreen := Arr[i * Width + j].G;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyBitmapWidth: Integer;
  MyBitmapHeight: Integer;
  Size: Cardinal;
  MyBitmapData: TMyBitmapData;
  bmp: TBitMap;
  x: Integer;
begin
  MyBitmapWidth := 100;
  MyBitmapHeight := 100;
  Size := MyBitmapWidth * MyBitmapHeight;
  SetLength(MyBitmapData, Size );

  for x := 0 to MyBitmapWidth - 1 do
  begin
    MyBitmapData[x * MyBitmapWidth + x].A := 255;
    MyBitmapData[x * MyBitmapWidth + x].R := 255;
  end;


  bmp := TBitMap.Create;
  try
    FillBitMap(bmp, MyBitmapData, MyBitmapWidth,MyBitmapHeight );
    Image1.picture.Assign(bmp);
  finally
    bmp.Free;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Your answer appears to make an entire new copy of the pixel data. I don't think that's what the question asks for. Rather, the question asks how to wrap a `TCanvas` object around the *existing* pixel buffer; the effect would be that calling methods on that `TCanvas` object would directly modify the contents of the original buffer.

Comment: @RobKennedy I'm not shure but I don't think its possible to use a external DBI structure for a Bitmap and it's HDC. Should I delete my post as Off Topic?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bummi but Rob is right. I would like to create a `TCanvas` object and draw on existing pixel data.